# Varchar field of size 0, but not listed in DISTINCT SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is not directly programming related so maybe it is off topic.

I have had this postgres table for some years now, for my photovoltaic. I do a query like

```
WITH all_sources AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT origin from solardata
    ORDER by origin
)
SELECT all_sources.origin, count(*) 
FROM solardata, all_sources
WHERE all_sources.origin = solardata.origin
GROUP BY all_sources.origin
ORDER BY all_sources.origin
```

and I get this result

```
                origin                | count  
--------------------------------------+--------
 kostal-log-parser: 10.1.log          |   5905
 kostal-log-parser: 5.5.log           |   6059
 kostal-log-parser: LogDaten_10_1.dat |   3474
 kostal-log-parser: LogDaten_5_5.dat  |   3369
 kostal-web-parser                    | 480869
 time-gridder                         |  18432
(6 rows)
```

but on the other side, if I run

```
select date_time, origin 
from solardata 
order by date_time limit 2;
```

I get

```
      date_time      | origin 
---------------------+--------
 2009-08-17 18:34:00 | 
 2009-08-17 18:34:00 |
```

How is that possible?

My postgres version is 9.4.5

---

Here is the solution. The reason was the inner join but i needed a left join.

```
WITH all_sources AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT origin from solardata
    ORDER by origin
)
SELECT all_sources.origin, count(*) 
FROM solardata
LEFT JOIN all_sources on (all_sources.origin = solardata.origin)
GROUP BY all_sources.origin
ORDER BY all_sources.origin
```

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data to recreate your case. Using `ORDER BY` in derived table is redundant and comma join is obsolete. Consider using `JOIN` syntax instad.

Comment: I am missing your point.  What is the question?  That two queries return different things isn't surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common table expression is redundant:

```
SELECT origin, count(*) 
from solardata 
GROUP BY origin 
ORDER BY origin;
```

The problem with your query is here:

```
WHERE   all_sources.origin = solardata.origin
```

`NULL = NULL => NULL(UKNOWN)` so the row is skipped.

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_GROUP_BY`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/896a5/3/0)**</kbd>
<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_Original`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/896a5/4/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════╗         ╔═════════╦═══════╗
║ origin  ║ count ║         ║ origin  ║ count ║
╠═════════╬═══════╣         ╠═════════╬═══════╣
║ (null)  ║     2 ║         ║         ║     2 ║
║         ║     2 ║   vs    ║ a       ║     1 ║
║ a       ║     1 ║         ║ b       ║     1 ║
║ b       ║     1 ║         ╚═════════╩═══════╝
╚═════════╩═══════╝
```

Note that `(null)` group does not exists in your version.

---

You shouldn't use it (redundant cte) but your query will work too if you change `=` to `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`:

```
WITH all_sources AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT origin from solardata
)
SELECT all_sources.origin, count(*) 
from solardata
JOIN all_sources
  ON all_sources.origin IS NOT DISTINCT FROM solardata.origin
GROUP BY all_sources.origin
ORDER BY all_sources.origin
```

Comment: Actually, that was the reason. Thank you for the hint and the solution with the join types.